# How to update value in cart total price?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am designing shopping cart mobile application using jQuery Mobile. I'm using a single page architecture to do navigation between pages. Every page has a CART icon in its header, where the current total price of basket showing. I have used KnockoutJS and on top of every page I am showing cart total price as:

```html
<a href="#cartBox" data-icon="myapp-settings" data-theme="b" data-role="button"><span data-bind="text: price"></span>  </a>
```

The above line I am using on every page header section.

This is the script I use to show price value every where:

```
function cartPrice() {
    this.price = ko.observable(0.00);
}
ko.applyBindings(new cartPrice());
```

There is a list view of products everywhere, now I want whenever user click on listview item then the price update with a value which is given in input type hidden in specific li having, and this value add in price current value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aggregate the `CartPrice` and the view model for your List view in one root view model. E.g. like this:

```js
function CartPrice() {
  this.price = ko.observable(0.00);
}

function ListViewModel() {
  var self = this, i = 1;
  
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.addItem = function() {
    self.items.push({
      name: "New item " + (++i),
      price: +(Math.random() * 2.5 + 1.0).toFixed(2)
    });
  }
}

function RootViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.cartPriceVm = new CartPrice();
  self.listVm = new ListViewModel();
  
  self.listVm.items.subscribe(function() {
    var newTotal = self.listVm.items().reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b.price; }, 0);
    //console.log(newTotal);
    self.cartPriceVm.price(newTotal);
  });
}

var vm = new RootViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko with: cartPriceVm -->
Total price: $<strong data-bind="text: price"></strong>.
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko with: listVm -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> -
    $<span data-bind="text: price"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return price }"
Message: price is not defined

Comment: Not in my snippet AFAICT. If you have a follow-up question you should ask it, along with a full repro (i.e. something like the snippet I've posted).